# jqxWindow in Data Table

Tags: php, mysql, jqxwidgets

can you help with my code. I want to view my remarks through jqxWindow of jqxWidgets. When you see my code below I insert the div id for remarks.

```
<?php
            include('connection.php');

            $sql = "SELECT en.transid, en.transdate, CONCAT(userlist.lname, ', ', userlist.fname, ' ', userlist.mname) AS sender_name,
                    userlist.`department`, en.document_number, doctype.document_type, doctype.document_description, vendor.`vendor_name`, en.`remarks`
                    FROM tbl_encode_transmittal en
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor vendor ON vendor.`vendor_id` =  en.vendor_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_doctype doctype ON doctype.`doc_id` = en.doctype_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist ON userlist.userid = en.sender_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_userlist userlist1 ON userlist1.userid = en.`receiver_id`
                    WHERE userlist1.`userid` = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'";

            $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tbody id=\"myTable\">";
                echo "<td><h6>" . $row['transid'] . "</h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6>" . $row['transdate'] . "</h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6>" . $row['sender_name'] . "</h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6>" . $row['department']. "</h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6>" . $row['document_number'] . "</h6></td>";
                echo "<td><h6>" . $row['document_type'] . " " . $row['document_description'] . "</h5></td>";
                echo "<td width=\"50\"><h6>" . $row['vendor_name'] . "</h6></td>";?>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top:10;"><a href="#" id="remarksBtn"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a></td>

                <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                <!--/////////                                Remarks Window Function                                     ////////// -->
                <!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <div id="window_remarks">
                    <div id="windowHeader">
                        <span>
                            Remarks
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="windowContent">
                    <?php
                        echo $row['remarks'];
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>  <!-- End Remarks Window Function -->
                <div class= "clear"></div>


            <?php } ?>
```

Here's my output guys. When I click the triggering image to view the jqxWindow that will show the remarks, it will not show the jqxWindow.

[image]